# PHP: How to insert a value into mysql using PHP before or after an existing value in mysql table. JSON/Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table...

It looks like this.

```
-----------------------------------
| Servername | Staffids             |
| MyServer   | ["1","2","3","4"]    |
-----------------------------------
```

I'm looking for a way to use PHP to insert a new ID into `Staffids` without removing the existing data. Example: I insert the ID 5 into Staffids and have it look like this `["1","2","3","4","5"]`

I've tried different ways but I end up erasing the existing data.

Comment: What is the definition of your table? What is the type of the column `StaffIds`? Assuming JSON, are you attempting to use the [JSON modification functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html) that MySQL provides in its query language? Please tell us more about what you've tried, and what you're targeting.

Comment: You could always fetch the data, update it localy and then execute a query to update it in your database.

Comment: It's a Varcher(255) column and it stores JSON/Array information of IDs for our server

Comment: If your column is simply a string, you will need to fetch the value and modify it before updating the record in the database - the database has no semantic meaning of the string in the column.

Comment: I've got it to work, thank you. I fetched the existing value and updated it with the new value in PHP successfully. I thank everyone who contributed.